# How to customize my code with Angular Devextreme?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, devexpress, devextreme

My Dev team are using Angular as a front-end framework, and ASP.net as a back-end framework and they had to use Devextreme and Devexpress as libraries or something ( please correct me if I'm wrong ), so the issue here is that my designs can not be implemented or as they say it's hard and it takes time to customize the code on Devextreme!
So what I'm asking is there any way to customize the Devextreme code, therefore to implement a professional_ kinda complicated too_ UI design ?

Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean by 'professional_ kinda complicated too_ UI design'. Try to start with [DevExtreme Theme Builder](https://devexpress.github.io/ThemeBuilder/).

Comment: Yes I tried that in fact but I have no control to adjust the grids for exemple or the text fields sizes and all that, I only can change colors !
And by ' Professional_kinda complicated too_ design ' I mean that I'm starting redesigning the whole web application and it's already made with DevExtreme, and the team here are trying to implement my design using DevExtreme and they're telling me it's hard to customize the code !
Can you please give any help !